# python how to mock 3rd party library response

Tags: python, patch, magicmock

I'm using a 3rd party library "mailjet" to send email.
Here's the doc: https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/getting-started/#prerequisites

This is the method in `send_email.py` that I want to test:

```
from mailjet_rest import Client

def send_email(email_content):
  client = Client(auth=(api_key, api_secret))
  response = client.send.create(data=email_content)
  if response.status_code != 200:
    // raise the error
  else:
    print(response.status_code)
    return response.status_code
...
```

I wanted to mock the status code. This is what I tried in `test_send_email.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
import unittest
import send_email

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("send_email.Client")
    def test_send_email(self, _mock):
        email_content = {...}
        _mock.return_value.status_code = 200
        response = send_email(email_content)
        // assert response == 200
```

When I run the test, it didn't print out the status code, it prints:

```
<MagicMock name='Client().send.create().status_code' id='140640470579328'>
```

How can I mock the status_code in the test? Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the attribute in the wrong place.

You mock the Client, which is correct, and put something in its return_value, which is also good.

However, the line

```
response = client.send.create(data=email_content)
```

applies on the return_value of your mock (client), the send attribute and its create method.

So what you need is to set the return_value.status_code of this create method.

```py
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("send_email.Client")
    def test_send_email(self, mock_client):
        email_content = {...}
        # this puts 200 in Client().status_code
        # mock_client.return_value.status_code = 200
        # that puts 200 in Client().send.create().status_code
        mock_client.return_value.send.create.return_value.status_code = 20
        response = send_email(email_content)
        assert response == 200
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean to set the return_value.status_code of this create method?

Comment: See my edit, you were putting status_code too high in your mock. I haven’t tested that code block since I’m not close to my computer at the moment, but should do the trick or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Finally got it, thank you!!!

Comment: @ljmc how to implement if testing django url that interact external package?